# Convert to Dame work, but captured not work... why?

Tags: java, bit

I have defined a `long` integer:

```
static long white1 = 0b101001011101001001101000110101000100101000010101000000L;
static long white2 = 0b101010110101010100101010010101010000101001111101001101L;
static long black1 = 0b100110010100110000100101111100101101100101011100101001L;
static long black2 = 0b100111111100111101100111011100111001100110110100110100L;
```

Game state:

```
static Long[] state = { white1, white2, black1, black2 };
```

Each of white and black has code 6 pawns.
I can't use std table to generate checkers.

If I go to pos x, 7 or x,0 i convert pawn to dame:

```
static void updateDame(byte n) {
    long apos = 1 << (n % 6) * 9 + 7;
    state[n / 6] = state[n / 6] + apos;
}
```

and this work.
but

```
static void updateCaptured(byte n) {
    long apos = 0 << (n % 6) * 9 + 8;
    state[n / 6] = state[n / 6] + apos;
}
```

Still not work... I need to change 9. bit to 0 from 1.
If I change 0 to 1 (like dame) it works.

If I try 1 (1+1 its 10 in binary) it won't work - captured near pawn...
How I can change it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    long apos = 0 << (n % 6) * 9 + 8;
```

Zero left-shifted is still zero.

Comment: but now its 1... i try 1 convert to 0.. i try ~1 or ``` long mask 0b100000000; apos = 1 ^ mask << (n%6)*9+8...``` but not work...

how fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to set or clear bits?   Then the appropriate operations are 'or' to set,'and not' to clear.    `state = state | bit`  , `state & ~bit`.     Or more succinctly,  `state |= bit`,  `state &= ~bit`.

Comment: i try   ``` state[n / 6] &= ~apos;```
but not work

Comment: Well, that's how you clear a bit.  There's no question of it.  What are you actually trying to achieve?   Where does the mysterious `n / 6` value come from?  Why are you clearing bits in `state` anyway?

Comment: state[] is build from 4 long... white1, white2, black1, black2... in 1 long are code 6 pawns... I calculate which is it... and i claculate whitch bit i must change...